# Constant difference between two percentage numbers (nonlinear)

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, nonlinear-system, percentages

I'm trying to figure out the correct way of detecting the difference of values based on two percentages, because my terminology is poor here is an example:

> The difference between two values where maximum value is 100 (%) is:
>   between 10 and 30 it is 20 between 60 and 80 it is 20
>
> So both differences are 20, although the difference between 10 and 30
>   is different in percentage then 60 to 80. What I see here is some sort
>   of non-linear function.
>
> So what do I want to achieve: If I want to say "send notification if
>   difference is more or equal 30", that would mean that I would get
>   notification if two numbers would be 10 and 40 (difference is 30), but
>   I wouldn't get any notification if the first number would be 75 as
>   there is no way the second would be more then 100 as the maximum is
>   100.

What I'm trying to get here is a way to know if two numbers differ on some scale. And that scale is not linear as I was tying to explain above. And in term, compare the results, if the "number1 vs number2 > minimum" -> fire notification.

Any idea what to search for?

I was trying to put some data into excel and get polinomic or logarithmic function but no success.

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: 20% of a quantity Q is 0.2Q. Why does it matter if 0.2 is the result of 30%-10% or 80%-60%?

Comment: Because I will miss out on cases where the first number is above 80, that means if I'm looking for a 0.2+ that won't happen because 100 is the maximum, right?

Comment: Ok - think that enables me to make a reasonable answer - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose 2 percentages are 0% < $a\%  < b\% $ < 100% and you want to notify when $(b - a)\%  \ \ge  x\% $ a suitable rule for notification that works for all percentage differences over x% would be $$fire\;if\;percentage\;is\;either\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{b - a \ge x,\;a \ge 0}\\{or\;a > 100 - x}\end{array}} \right.$$

Any good?

Comment: Maybe I'm over complicating things but this seems a bit off, why would I want to fire when b < x? This would mean if the first number is 15 and is smaller then the mark 20 would fire off. Does not make sense. Other two seem reseonable, thank you for your input

Comment: Didn't understand what should happen if the percentages were near the 0% end instead of the 100% end.

Comment: By the way - it is customary to accept answers that you find useful. Thanks ...